# SPARK Steaming updateStateByKey values from previous Microbatch when no new such data for current Microbatch

Tags: spark-streaming

It is unclear to me if I want to show the top N ocurrences over all Microbatches to-date for some key with simple counts, whether this is possible with standard Spark Streaming when not UNIONing or JOINing in an appropriate manner! with a saved / persisted set of data taking into account that current processing may not have keys to process that were in the top 5.

I.e. If the top 5 for current processing of an initial Microbatch are x,y,z,a,b and, then if, say, the next Microbatch has x,c,m only as data, can I retrieve a, b and y and z as part of the top 5 if c and m have less occurrences than these priors in terms of top 5?

May be it is a bad Use Case.

Comment: In hindsight documentation is unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
rdd1 = sc.parallelize(list('abcd')).map(lambda x: (x, 110 - ord(x)))
rdd2 = sc.parallelize(list('cdef')).map(lambda x: (x, 2))

rddQueue = ssc.queueStream([rdd1, rdd2])


def func(new_values, old_value):
    return sum(new_values) + (old_value or 0)


rddQueue = rddQueue.updateStateByKey(func).transform(lambda x: x.sortBy(lambda y: y[1], ascending=False))

rddQueue.pprint()
```

output:

```
-------------------------------------------                                     
Time: 2016-12-16 11:06:54
-------------------------------------------
('a', 13)
('b', 12)
('c', 11)
('d', 10)

-------------------------------------------                                     
Time: 2016-12-16 11:06:57
-------------------------------------------
('a', 13)
('c', 13)
('b', 12)
('d', 12)
('f', 2)
('e', 2)
```

'retrieve' means what?

Comment: Whilst the problem is conceptually easy I cannot see how the above actually relates to a typical Dstream updated over successive micro batches / windows. I found this link https://www.rittmanmead.com/blog/2015/08/combining-spark-streaming-and-data-frames-for-near-real-time-log-analysis/ and get the impression that some persisting may be needed. Can you provide the complete code by any chance as I am a seasoned campaigner but reasonably new on Sp Str?